# Angular in Netbeans, routing doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, netbeans, routes

I try to build my first AngularJS project in Netbeans.
But when I run my browser, I don't see my homeview.
When I click Home in the nav I get the following exception:

> Cannot open http://localhost:8383/home

Below, you can see the code of my navigation:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/over">About us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have following app.js file:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
              controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          })
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

What is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hit the url " http://localhost:8383/#/home" to use the angular routing

Comment: so I need to do <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li> ?

Comment: yes.because '/' would redirect to the server url and angular uses '#' to maintain routing